# How to dynamically add attributes to class so that they can be accessed by instances in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I tried to write a common factory function that create custom enum object, but instance can't get correct properties.

This is an online preview of the address https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rkl1zr

**Environment**

typescript 3.6.2

Here's my code:

```
type IConfig<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: IOption
}

export interface IOption {
  value: number
  label: string
}

class Factory<T> {
  [key: keyof T]: any // An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.
  config: IConfig<T>
  options: IOption[]
  constructor(config: IConfig<T>) {
    this.options = []
    this.config = config
    for (let key in config) {
      this.options.push(config[key])
      this[key] = config[key].value // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'this[Extract<keyof T, string>]'.
    }
  }
}

const data = {
  NORMAL: {
    value: 1,
    label: 'NORMAL'
  },
  ABNORMAL: {
    value: 0,
    label: 'ABNORMAL',
  },
}

const CommonStatus = new Factory<typeof data>(data)

CommonStatus.NORMAL // No Intelligent Tips
```

I expect `CommonStatus` to have the correct type so that I can access the properties declared(`NORMAL` and `ABNORMAL`) in the constructor without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code as posted I'm not sure why you care about `T` if you only ever look at `keyof T`... the property value types of `T` are always ignored, so you probably don't need the `Factory` type to carry them around.  So instead of `Factory<T>`, I'll change it to `Factory<K extends string>`, and instead of `IConfig<T>`, I will change it to [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)`<K, IOption>`.  You can keep it the original way if your use case cares about the value types of `T[keyof T]`; it doesn't affect the rest of the answer.

---

There isn't an easy and completely type-safe solution here, unfortunately.  TypeScript doesn't support [classes extending arbitrary generic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13807), even with [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html).  You can only extend types whose keys are known *statically*, which isn't the case with something like `K`, keys which are only known dynamically.

What you can do is make something which uses [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) inside the class implementation to make up for the lack of ability to have arbitrary keys in `this`, and then use a further type assertion to produce a version of the class that users can access which behaves the way you want.

Here goes:

```
class _Factory<K extends string> {
  config: Record<K, IOption>;
  options: IOption[];
  constructor(config: Record<K, IOption>) {
    this.options = [];
    this.config = config;
    for (let key in config) {
      this.options.push(config[key]);
      this[key as keyof this] = config[key].value as any; // assertion
    }
  }
}

type Factory<K extends string> = _Factory<K> & Record<K, number>;
const Factory = _Factory as new <K extends string>(
  config: Record<K, IOption>
) => Factory<K>;
```

So, I renamed `Factory<K>` out of the way to `_Factory<K>`, which doesn't even try to have dynamic keys.    Inside the constructor the assignment to `this` properties has a bunch of type assertions to prevent the compiler from complaining.

After that, we have a type named `Factory<K>` and a value named `Factory` which act just like your intended versions.  The type `Factory<K>` is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of `_Factory<K>` with `Record<K, number>`, so an object of type `Factory<K>` has both the `config` and `options` properties from `_Factory<K>`, as well as numeric-valued properties in `K`.

Let's see if it works:

```
const data = {
  NORMAL: {
    value: 1,
    label: "NORMAL",
    c: 1
  },
  ABNORMAL: {
    value: 0,
    label: "ABNORMAL"
  }
};

const CommonStatus = new Factory(data);
CommonStatus.ABNORMAL; // number
CommonStatus.NORMAL; // number
CommonStatus.config.ABNORMAL; // IOption
CommonStatus.config.NORMAL; // IOption
CommonStatus.options; // IOption[]
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQHkwYEIk4BvAKDjgDdMAbAV2AC44kWBbAIzQBuWnCaYBTTgGcYUZAHNhAX2rVsYqVLgB9AGI4Y0AJ4AeANJxQqJABMtMuUnkA+KiOzl0CeZwBKwDygbcwAaAmJScmdhOggSMiQpTiJ48gBtAF0YuA9E2RZsQygAClyvHzh-QOCzMJTIpGcASjc6OhgACwQpADo4hq0AXjhM7Pau3rLvOGGpxRE6dGg4YqZgeABrYCNECjmWmja2zu6+1MSesBYpDtLPbzStowymseOJx+24TC0niHQ4CcpBkZjl7vJPs8eoxWHgft8kEZBHAAPQo76aNANBZwFR0FQqGBGMB4fSFYzmSwgax2OAOBSuYZ6AwUsyuABklQC0BqYW4-DQ0TU5BkcDJRR2TPFxgxXGAAHc4JSrMBbPZZAziu5wX5uUFQuFzs5qC1Bq5pVBTGzhMK8nAbJgYJhQYc4AA5Qi+ACyAEEADKcV10GFsTgARhCOLEEk4ACIPd7-bHI0dsOGREoU3AfQAhBO+gOtNohjhwAAMWbo0eAkjgsdz+aTGeoShtuVFAGEIDweOQAMpOmDXUFIBVilmW4oOp2vahdnv9wfXHoNz0F5Fori8ARQOfd3tIAeO5eNv0b9H8nd7heHpeTcErvNr-3nw3Y+cHo9D+9Ico9U+vvUCTXp+d5nAMgERAkmTUEAA)